# Install npm does not work on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs, npm

Install npm does not work on windows

**Error**

> npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: grunt-rename@'>=0.4.1-0
>   <0.5.0-0'
>
> npm ERR! Valid install targets:
>
> npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4"]
>
> npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\
>
> npm\lib\cache.js:719:10)
>
> npm ERR!     at next (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.j
>
> s:698:17)
>
> npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:675:
>
> 5
>
> npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
>
> es\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:142:7)
>
> npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\grac
>
> eful-fs\polyfills.js:133:7
>
> npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
>
> npm ERR!     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! or email it to:
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe"
>   "C:\Program File
>
> s (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>
> npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\ra824041\Desktop\grunt\MyApp npm ERR! node -v
>   v0.10.15
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-compress
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-nodeunit
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-stripcomments
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-usemin
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-copy
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-minified/0.0.6
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-qunit
>
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-cssmin
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\ra824041\Desktop\grunt\Greece 3.6\npm-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ML",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-rename": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-minified": "0.0.6",
    "grunt-stripcomments": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: How I can see the NPM error log to check the versions comability? I have some troubles with NPM on Windows. I created an issue, but it didn't solved for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335043/troubles-with-npm-and-node-gyp-in-windows
Maybe you have some useful advices for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an issue on the first line:

```
No compatible version found: grunt-rename@'>=0.4.1-0 <0.5.0-0'
```

Update grunt-rename in the package.json to any of  ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4"]

Be sure to try an "npm cache clean" commands too