# Troubles with NPM and node-gyp in Windows

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-watch

I have some troubles with npm packages on my Windows workstation... I have a set of NPM dependencies in my [`package.json`](https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/package.json) file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.22",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.3",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.12.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1"
  }
```

And when I trying to run `npm install` I get the strange error related to `node-gyp` package and something like `\msbuild.exe`.

Here is the error:

```
c:\Users\dmytro.medvid\sites\evolution\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp
-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
c:\Users\dmytro.medvid\sites\evolution\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.
props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Users\dmytro.medvid\sites\evolution\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON evolution@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Can someone help to figure out with it issue? I'm not experienced windows user, but at the moment I should work with Windows :(

**UPDATED:** Here is the [errors log](https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/errors.log) which I update every time with new NPM errors.

**System details:** Windows 7 Enterprice 64-bit operating system

**Node version:** v5.1.0

**NPM version:** v3.3.12

**Python Version:** v2.7.1

Also I installed [Microsoft Visual C++ build tools](http://microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159) (provided in answer below). Version 14.0

Comment: I checked my environment variables, and all looks OK. Also I checked that I have access to python in CMD. Python version is 2.7.1.

Comment: Also I installed Microsoft Visual C++ build tools using this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159 (provided in answer below). Version of Microsoft Visual C++ build tools is 14

Comment: It works for me https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

Answer (score 17):

Write those code in admin command prompt:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

And then hit enter.

Comment: do i need to restart my machine for this? I ran that one but still getting an error.

Answer (score 5):

You need Microsoft Visual C++ build tools, which are packaged with Visual Studio. However, they are now also available as a [standalone download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48159). After installing these tools and restarting your computer, you should be able to install packages that use node-gyp under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try it now. Why work under the Windows is so painful?

Comment: I installed this extension and looks like it helped to solve the problem. But I got new one related to node-gyp...
Here is the errors log, I commited it to Git: https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/errors.log

Comment: That should work, try removing node_modules and running `npm cache clean`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do it, but I got the errors with msbuild tool... Also I updated the error log with last errors (https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/errors.log). Not sure why it happens... Please, can you check the error log and try to help me with this issue

Comment: Can you try `npm i utf-8-validate --msvs_version=2015`

Comment: I tried it. But the same result is presented. I updated error log with latest errors: https://github.com/web-jenezis/jenezis-project-bootstrap/blob/master/errors.log

Comment: Will try to do this on Unix system... but at the moment this problem not resolved for me.. :(

Answer (score 3):

Windows open PowerShell in administrative tool and run this command

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

You should do following cmd: (In my computer, I installed vc2015)

**$ node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015**

Answer (score 0):

I created an [issue on github for node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/849). And also [here is a disscussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/779) of a similar problem. Probaly it not helped me, but maybe it can be useful for someone else.